# Mapping m to right ctrl+right shift+q+z

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to map <kbd>m</kbd> to <kbd>right ctrl</kbd><kbd>right shift</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>. 
My attempt is

```
m::Send, ^+qz
```

I executed the file but this is not working.

Comment: Your script seems to work for me, though it is not specifically sending the **right** ctrl and shift. Can you clarify if you intend to have Ctrl+Shift+Q followed by Ctrl+Shift+Z, or if you needed all four down at the same time like Ctrl+Shift+Q+Z?

Comment: I need all 4 at the same time specifically sending the right ctrl and shift

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a cleaner way to do this, but this should be an explicit way to tell it what you want to do.

```
m::Send, {RCtrl Down}{RShift Down}{q Down}{z Down}{z Up}{q Up}{RShift Up}{RCtrl Up}
```

You can use `RCtrl` or `<^` to specify the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>. You can use the `Down` and `Up` commands inside `{}` braces to specify keydown and keyup events.